# How can I add a empty attribute to my video tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I just would like to add the 'autobuffer' attribute to my video tag using javascript.

Basically:

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.addAttribute('autoBuffer');
```

And I'll have:

```
<video autoBuffer></video>
```

I tried:

```
video.setAttribute('autoBuffer'); => <video autoBuffer="undefined"></video>
```

Which is wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter to [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) must be a string always - currently the `undefined` you're implicitly passing is converted to one. Use

```
video.setAttribute('autoBuffer', '');
```

Comment: Quick, nice, right! Can't believe I haven't tried that... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I did it:

```
Element.prototype.addAttribute = function(strAttribute = "") { if (!this.attributes[strAttribute]) { this.toggleAttribute(strAttribute); } }
```

It only adds it if it's not present. Originally I named it "touchAttribute" but I renamed it for your case.

If you are completely sure the attribute is not present in the Element you can use `video.toggleAttribute("autoBuffer");`